# Calling html2text iteratively on a set of htmls not working

Tags: python, subprocess, piping

This is the code snippet:

```
for i in obj:
    url = "someurl" + i
    oars = requests.get(url, timeout=1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(oars.content)
    fout = open(i + ".html", "wt")
    print((type(soup.prettify)))
    fout.write(oars.text)
    oars.close
    #fout.write(soup.get_text())
    # Still not working, using zsh for now
    if call("html2text " + i + ".html" + ">" + i + ".txt", shell=True) == 0:
        print("yay")
        #call("rm -f " + i + ".html", shell=True)
    else:
        print(i)
```

But html2text is just creating empty txt files rather than properly piping the output.
I even tried replacing `html2text` with `elinks -dump` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but this might be what you're after

```
import subprocess
import sys

outfile = i + ".txt"


cmd = sys.path[0] + "/htmltotext " + i + ".html"

with open(outfile, "w") as output_f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=output_f, shell=True)
```

Comment: sys.path was not needed. Otherwise works like a charm. So does piping not work properly via `call` function?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use `html2text` as a Python library?

```
h = html2text.HTML2Text()
txt = h.handle(open(infile).read())
```